# Symfony2 Extra fields FormError on validating form with hidden field

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

Here is listing of my form:

```
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder($project)
                ->add('name','text')
                ->add('type','choice', array(
                    'choices'  => $enumtype
                   ))
                ->add('begindate','date')
                ->add('expecteddate','date')
                ->add('events', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new EventType(),
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    ))

                ->add('financial', 'file', array(
                    'property_path' => false,
                    'required' => false
                    ))
                ->add('investition', 'file', array(
                    'property_path' => false,
                    'required' => false
                    ));
if ($defaults) {
    $builder->add('id','hidden',array('data' => $defaults['id'], 'property_path' => false));
    $form = $builder->getForm();
    $form->setData($defaults);
}
else
    $form = $builder->getForm();
```

When i try to validate this form, i receive FormError object:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Symfony\Component\Form\FormError Object  (
        [messageTemplate:protected] => This form should not contain extra fields.
        [messageParameters:protected] => Array (
            [{{ extra_fields }}] => id 
        )
        [messagePluralization:protected] =>
    )
)
```

If i exclude "id" field - all works ok. 
How can i use hidden type and make validation?

Comment: Are you using a standalone form class or are you binding this to an Entity? If the latter, odds are you are binding to an undefined property (id) or it is the primary key which cannot be set in a form this way.

Comment: I'm binding this to an Entity, but this is undefined property. Name does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue comes from the fact that the hidden parameter is optionnal.

A common mistake is not to set the associated type when submitting the form.

Example of mistake:

```
public function addOrEditAction($id=null)
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if (!$id) {
        $model = new Actu();
        $type  = new ActuType(); /* I do not set the default id on submit */
    } else {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $model = $em->getRepository("MyBundle:Actu")
                    ->find($id);
        if (!$model) {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admAddNew'));
        } else {
            $type = new ActuType($model->getId());
        }
    }

    $form = $this->createForm($type,$model);

    if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($model);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admNews'));
        }
    }

    $data = array('form'=>$form->createView());
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Page:news-add.html.twig',$data);
}
```

**When calling the controller**
`ActuType()` contains:

```
'name', 'content', 'date', 'id'
```

**When Submitting the form**
`ActuType()` contains:

```
'name', 'content', 'date'
```

They do not match.
This actually returns an error because there's an extra field with hidden `id` containing the row to edit when submitting the form.

All you need to do is to check the request before initializing FormType

```
if (!$id && null === $id = $request->request->get('newsType[id]',null,true)) {
```

With this, you can set the same FormType that you did when asking for the page